# Setup all properties of a mock of a given type to return a value

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I would like to make my mock (using Moq) to return a given DateTime for every property in it that is of type DateTime.

How can I do it?

I've tried with `mock.SetupAllProperties()` but it doesn't accept any configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should be fine for your use case:

```
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
mock.SetReturnsDefault(DateTime.Now);
```

`SetReturnsDefault` sets default return value for all methods and properties of specified type (so if you pass instance of `DateTime` there - that will be default value of all properties and methods that return `DateTime`).